# Can I pass a list of colors for points to matplotlib's 'Axes.plot()'?

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot

I've got a lot of points to plot and am noticing that plotting them individually in [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/index.html#) takes much longer (more than *100 times longer*, according to [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)) than plotting them all at once.

However, I need to color code the points (based on data associated with each one) and can't figure out how to plot more than one color for a given call to [`Axes.plot()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.plot). For example, I can get a result similar to the one I want with something like

```
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
rands = numpy.random.random_sample((10000,))
for x in range(10000):
    ax.plot(x, rands[x], 'o', color=str(rands[x]))
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

but would rather do something much faster like

```
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
rands = numpy.random.random_sample((10000,))
# List of colors doesn't work
ax.plot(range(10000), rands, 'o', color=[str(y) for y in rands])
matplotlib.pyplot.show()
```

but providing a list as the value for `color` doesn't work in this way.

Is there a way to provide a list of colors (and for that matter, edge colors, face colors , shapes, z-order, etc.) to `Axes.plot()` so that each point can potentially be customized, but all points can be plotted at once?

---

Using [`Axes.scatter()`](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.scatter) seems to get part way there, since it allows for individual setting of point color; but color is as far as that seems to go. (`Axes.scatter()` also lays out the figure completely differently.)

Comment: Note: In the actual application, the points need to be colored according to other data associated with each point, not just with the y value (so no shortcut that relies on that will help). Changing `mark` would also be helpful in some cases (so: same question for `mark`). And the ordering of the points must be preserved.

Comment: Did you look at using `scatter` instead of `plot`?  There you can also use a color map to specify the color.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I've inherited the code (and don't have complete control over it). Can I simply replace my `ax.plot()` — or `for ... ax.plot()` with `ax.scatter()`? That would be brilliant!

Comment: Look at the documentation for `scatter` in the matplotlib documentation and familiarize yourself with how to use it.  Then you will know whether you can use it or not.  It's hard to know whether you will be able to use it without knowing what you can and can't change.  (For instance, if you don't have control over the code, you might not be even able to change the `plot` version to work the way you want, right?)

Comment: @BrenBarn: Basically, I can get the lists I need for all the data (all of the x and y coordinates, and all the colors they should have, in order); I can call any method on `ax` (as in the example) instead of any `plot` calls. However I can't change how the axes are set up (all the calls to `set` have already happened, for example).

Comment: @BrenBarn: FWIW, it turns out that `scatter` doesn't work. I lacks many of the arguments that `plot` has (notably `mfc` and `mec`) and doesn't allow for `marker` to be a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is about 5 times faster for me to create the objects (patches) directly. To illustrate the example, I have changed the limits (which have to be set manually with this method). The circle themselves are draw with [`matplotlib.path.Path.circle`](http://matplotlib.org/api/path_api.html?highlight=circle#matplotlib.path.Path.circle). Minimal working example:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
rands = np.random.random_sample((N,))

patches = []
colors  = []

for x in range(N):
    C = Circle((x/float(N), rands[x]), .01)
    colors.append([rands[x],rands[x],rands[x]])
    patches.append(C)

plt.axis('equal')
ax.set_xlim(0,1)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)

collection = PatchCollection(patches)
collection.set_facecolor(colors)
ax.add_collection(collection)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's considerably faster. I have some trouble with `matplotlib.pyplot.axis('equal')`, because in my actual scenario I have a different figure ratio, and I'm not sure how to handle the circles in that case. I've got something like `fig.set_size_inches(fig_ratio*fig.get_size_inches()[1], fig.get_size_inches()[1])` where `fig_ratio = 1.675`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius The reason why the original version was so slow was due to the fact that you were creating `N` different plot objects - each one of these has a significant creation time. As for the scale problem, I'd rescale your data to [0,1] and simply change the labels on the axes (this is what I've done in the past).

Comment: I'll give it a try. Scaling stuff is my big stumbling block for some reason.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Also with this many data points, you may want to consider a heatmap of some kind, you may lose the information density by the overlay of too many points.

Comment: Also, I assume that with patches/circles I have the full control I need over edge color, face color, opacity, etc.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius Correct, but you'll do that mostly with the `PatchCollection` and not with the `Circle`'s themselves. The docs are useful here.

Comment: Not [enough data](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Exoplanet_Period-Mass_Scatter_History.gif) for a heatmap yet; maybe soon.

Comment: This works for me, but [I wonder now about what the Pythonic way to plot large numbers of points is](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26787416/656912), since this approach (which I see a lot, now that I look) breaks the abstraction of plotting points.