# What is the Pythonic way to plot large numbers of points with varying appearance?

Tags: python, performance, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot large numbers of points that have varying appearance (shape, edge color, face, color, etc.) and am finding that plotting the obvious way (using `plot` for each point) takes a very long time. I see various ways to improve performance, but find that these either reduce flexibility in point appearance, or end up being far more low level than seems correct to me.

For example, if I have

```
fig, ax = matplotlib.pyplot.subplots()
rands = numpy.random.random_sample((n,))
```

where `n` is some large number, then using `plot` to plot each point

```
for x in range(n):
    ax.plot(x, rands[x], 'o', color=str(rands[x]), mec=str(1-rands[x]))
```

takes a very long time and seems very inefficient. Much faster results can be achieved with by plotting many points at once

```
ax.plot(range(n), rands, 'o', color='b', mec='r')
```

but with a loss of control over many features of the individual points (here, for example neither `color` nor `mec` can be a list, and many other aspects suffer the same limitation). Using convenience methods like `scatter`

```
ax.scatter(range(n), rands, marker='o', color=[str(y) for y in rands])
```

also produces fast results; but again at the loss of considerable flexibility (though points can be colored individually, `plot`'s remaining options for setting features of individual points are not supported) and of some automatic axis limiting (use of `set_xlim` and `set_ylim` seem necessary to accomplish what `plot` does automatically).

Finally, I see many examples that use graphic elements like circles in conjunction with [collections](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html) which, while "fast for common use cases", result in code that looks to "low level" to me

```
patches = []
colors  = []

for x in range(n):
    circ = matplotlib.patches.Circle((x/float(n), rands[x]), .01)
    colors.append([rands[x],rands[x],rands[x]])
    patches.append(circ)

collection = matplotlib.collections.PatchCollection(patches)
collection.set_facecolor(colors)
collection.set_edgecolor([[1-h for h in c] for c in colors])
ax.add_collection(collection)
```

since it not only *breaks the abstraction of plotting points*, but also requires considerable scaling and adjustment to restore (even partially) the appearance provided automatically by `plot` (here for example `matplotlib.pyplot.axis('equal')` is necessary to avoid distorted "points").

This is frustrating because `plot` seems the natural method to use as it provides all the right customization of individual points, and results in figures that are nicely scaled and with axes that are naturally bounded — it's just too slow when used a point at a time, and doesn't accept lists as arguments for most properties.

What is the correct Pythonic way to plot large numbers of points where features of each point (marker, edge color, face color, alpha, size, etc.) must potentially be customized? Is using circles (or other shapes) and collections (followed by scaling and other tweaking of the figure) really the preferred (or at least necessary) approach?

Comment: Following up on the previous discussion  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26764169/249341, I think that it would make sense to write yourself a custom plot function *once* that does what you need (e.g. variable sizes, etc) and use that for all future projects. More customizability could be submitted a request to the matplotlib team. There are several active developers here on this site, perhaps they will give you some tips.

Comment: @Hooked: Yes. The question though is whether even such a custom function would be the Pythonic way. And agreed: It would be great to see `plot`'s point style parameters take lists as arguments. As it is, it seems like one has to give up on plotting and switch to *drawing* (which if true, seems a serious shortcoming).

Answer (score -2):

I've done python plotting in two ways:

1. pychart: Hasn't been released since 2006, so I stopped using it.
2. gnuplot: Written in C, may be fast for your purposes, and is pretty
       flexible.  This amounts to writing a gnuplot file and feeding it to the gnuplot binary.